# What are equality operators and how many are there?

Tags: python, operators, equality

Are these all the operators in Python or are there more?

```
==, !=, >=, <=
```

Comment: Equality operators can have a variety of inputs, but have Boolean outputs only (True or False).   So `a==1` , `word=="Sarah"`, `word!='Sarah'` are all expressions that test equality. The `<`,`<=`,`>`,`>=` operators go further to compare numbers. You often use such expressions in `if.. else` conditions.

Comment: What do you need help with? Have you even done a search? I can assure you that the [python docs](http://docs.python.org) contain this information.

Answer (score 1):

[Operators in python docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lzVh.png)

The equality operators are the ones with the = sign before them, so yes they are the only ones :)

**BUT**

If you are ever unsure of anything regarding syntax or usage your best bet is Python Docs, it's even available offline with a quick press on F1 in IDLE as well as being on the internet.